# Threading issue with MediaPlayer C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, error-handling

I am creating an app that has an `9x9` multidimensional array full of custom objects, and when a button is pressed a sound specific to every single object needs to be played.

I run this method to load the sound, runs with no known problems:

```
   public void setSoundToPlay()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDiag = new OpenFileDialog();
        if ((bool)openFileDiag.ShowDialog())
        {
            audio = new MediaPlayer();
            audio.Open(new System.Uri(openFileDiag.FileName));
        }

    }
```

but when I activate another method to play sound:

```
    public void buttonActivated()
    {
                audio.Play();
    }
```

I get a `System.InvalidOperationException:{"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}`

The object running the mediaplayer object is nested within another object, is that the problem. I tried understanding threading but have made no headway.

I also need to, in some cases, need to have all the sounds be able to play at once. Is this the best object for the job?

Comment: Where does setSoundToPlay get called? Basically you're trying to call audio.Play from the UI thread but audio is owned by another thread

Answer (score 2):

Use the Dispatcher property associated with the media player element, like this

```
 public void buttonActivated()
 { 
   audio.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                audio.Play();
            });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To access devices like this from other methods use

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => objectName);
```